# PHP - Validity of appending string to new variable

Tags: php, variables, syntax, runtime-error

```
$var .= "hello";
echo $var;
```

Is the above block of code valid or will it generate notices / errors under some circumstances?

If no should `$var = ""` or just `$var` be added before the block of code?

Comment: as a best practice you need to declare `$var = ""` first.

Comment: You must declare your variable first before passing some value into it

Answer (score 2):

Above block of code will generate notice the following notice:

> Undefined variable: var

Variables should be defined before they are used in code, see example below:

```
<?php
    $var = '';
    $var .= "hello";
    echo $var;
?>
```